# In Corda, how to define an InitiatedBy flow without defining the Initiating flow?

Tags: corda

I would like to create an `InitiatedBy` flow that is initiated by a flow class defined in another CorDapp. I do not have the source files of the other CorDapp, which is written and maintained by another company.

How can I write the `IntiatedBy` flow in my CorDapp such that it can be initiated by an initiating flow defined in a different CorDapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Corda 4, you can specify which responder flow to use via the node configuration. See https://docs.corda.net/head/flow-overriding.html#overriding-a-flow-via-node-configuration.

In Corda 3 and earlier, you need to create an abstract class that has the same fully-qualfiied name as the flow that will initiate your `InitiatedBy` flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
abstract class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>()
```

Then use this class in the `InitiatedBy` annotation of your flow:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // TODO: Flow response logic.
    }
}
```

The `Responder` flow will now respond to any initiating flows with the name `Initiator`, regardless of the actual class being run on the other side.

Comment: If flows are written independently by the two parties in a flow an deployed in separate jars will Corda still able to connect these two flows?

Comment: @AustinMoothart The mapping is based on fully-qualified class names. I'll update the above to make that clear. I've also documented the new Corda 4 config options.